# WTForm validate_on_submit() returns False for selectField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

**Edit, Solved:** The `validate()` method which `validate_on_submit()` calls requires the values for `SelectField` options to be integers. Adding the `coerce=int` option to the `SelectField` solved the problem. The field now looks like this:

```
time_zone = SelectField('Time Zone', choices=[(-1, '--Select Time Zone--'),(0, 'PST'), (1, 'MST'), (2, 'EST')], coerce=int)
```

**Original Post:**

I am working on a registration form using WTForms (v2.2.1) in Flask(v1.1.1). When I have a `SelectField` in the form class `form.validate_on_submit()` automatically returns `False`

I followed the pattern in the [documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField) and looked through most of the "Similar questions" SO suggests to no avail. Many of the other posts are missing `{{ form.csrf_token }}` or `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` below the form tag. I've tried both with the same outcome.

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError


class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):    
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email Address', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    phone = StringField('Phone Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    time_zone = SelectField('Time Zone', choices=[(-1, '--Select Time Zone--'),(0, 'PST'), (1, 'MST'), (2, 'EST')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

**index.html** (The form is rendered on the index.html page and processed in the /register route)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="flex-item p-5 register">
    <h2>Register</h2>

    <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="post" novalidate>
      {{ register_form.hidden_tag() }}

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ register_form.first_name.label }}
          {{ register_form.first_name(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ register_form.last_name.label }}
          {{ register_form.last_name(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
          {{ register_form.email.label }}
          {{ register_form.email(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
          {{ register_form.phone.label }}
          {{ register_form.phone(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
          {{ register_form.password.label }}
          {{ register_form.password(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
          {{ register_form.confirm_password.label }}
          {{ register_form.confirm_password(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
          {{ register_form.time_zone.label }}
          {{ register_form.time_zone(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
      </div>

      {{ register_form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}      

    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from app import app
from app.forms import RegisterForm

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', register_form=RegisterForm())

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()

    print(form.is_submitted(), form.validate())
    # This is printing (True, False) when there is a SelectField
    # and (True, True) when no SelectField is in the RegisterForm Class
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('validating register form')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

If I remove the `SelectField` from the RegisterForm class, `validate_on_submit()` works fine.

Any thoughts on what is causing this issue?

Comment: How does it fail? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24578039/4799172) and you'll see why it failed

Comment: @roganjosh, how do I figure that out? There isn't much info in the documentation, and it looks to return a boolean value. Just saw your link... looking into it, thanks!

Comment: @roganjosh The error is 'Not a valid choice'

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that it's because you have `-1` but I'm not sure. Before `validate_on_submit` can you do `print(form.to_dict())`?

Comment: @roganjosh I tried the SelectField without the -1 choice and it has the same result. printing ```to_dict()``` results in: { ..., 'time-zone': '2', ...}. Is it something to do with the value being a string not an int?

Comment: That was it! I added ```coerce=int``` to the ```SelectField``` and it works. Thanks so much for walking me through debugging!